# unity Subtraction Issue - Beginner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I have a really basic problem.

I want to display the score on my TextBox and add +1 when the "OK" button is clicked and subtract -5 when the "NO" button is clicked.

But now I have the problem that it seems to me that the subtraction doesn't really work. Only one instance is displayed on the TextBox, i.e. if I click OK 10x in a row, I have 10 Points. If I now click on NO, the text field immediately shows -5, but it should be subtracted. If I click OK again, then I'll have 11 points, which shouldn't be the case, it should be 6.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Clicked : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject NO;
    public GameObject OK;
    public Text Points;
    public int score;
   
    public void OnClick()
    {
        Score(1);
        OK.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(90, Camera.main.pixelWidth - 90), Random.Range(90, Camera.main.pixelHeight - 90));
        double rnd = Random.Range(0, 11);
        if (rnd == 1)
        {
            NO.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(90, Camera.main.pixelWidth - 90), Random.Range(90, Camera.main.pixelHeight - 90));
            NO.SetActive(true);

        }
        else
        {
            NO.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    public void Score(int points)
    {
        if(points == 5)
        {
            score = score - 5;
            Points.text = "Punkte : "+score;
        }
        else if(points == 1)
        {
            score++;
            Points.text = "Punkte : "+score;
        }
       
    }
    public void OnClickNo()
    {
        Score(5);
        NO.SetActive(false);

    }

    void Start()
    {
        NO.SetActive(false);
      
        Points.text = "Punkte : " + score;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
I changed now everything, removed the connection to all controls, add only one to it and add a Listener at start method.
It seems now to work.
Thanks :)

```
public class Clicked : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text Points;
    public int score = 0;


    [SerializeField]
    private Button OK;

    [SerializeField]
    private Button NO;


    public Button SelectedButton
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Points.text = "Punkte : " + score;
        NO.onClick.AddListener(() => SelectButton(NO));
        OK.onClick.AddListener(() => SelectButton(OK));
    }

    public void SelectButton(Button button)
    {
        SelectedButton = button;
        if(button == OK)
        {
            score++;
            Points.text = "Punkte : " + score;
            OK.enabled = (SelectedButton == OK);
            OK.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(90, Camera.main.pixelWidth - 90), Random.Range(90, Camera.main.pixelHeight - 90));
            double rnd = Random.Range(0, 5);
            if (rnd == 1)
            {
                NO.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(90, Camera.main.pixelWidth - 90), Random.Range(90, Camera.main.pixelHeight - 90));

            }
        }
        else if(button == NO)
        {
            score -= 5;
            Points.text = "Punkte : " + score;
            NO.enabled = (SelectedButton == NO);
            NO.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(90, Camera.main.pixelWidth - 90), Random.Range(90, Camera.main.pixelHeight - 90));

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have two instances of this script running (with both of them having the same objects lined)?

Comment: i attached the script to Button OK and Button NO. is this what you mean? so both of them have control to the Same Score.TextBox

Comment: That does sound like you have two instances of the script - both of which have their own `score` values, not connected to each other. You need to make sure there is only one instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a single script that will handle both button clicks. At the moment you have two scripts, each one with its own `score` variable. Place your script to the object (usually root object for both buttons is used for this). Then point both buttons onClick method to this script. It should do the trick.

Comment: But this is what i do. I have one script and drag & drop it to the controls (add component). I have 2 buttons. If i didnt attach it to it, it wont work.

Comment: You attached it to both buttons. so you create two instances of your script. and each instance has its own `score` variable. That's why you see -5 after clicking NO. Because this instance had a 0 score before. And the second instance still has 10.

Comment: ok i understand now.. i thought it works like c# but it doesn't^^ do you have a solution for me, bcs i don't really understand how to solve this now. I only see the option to connect them to each other to manage this. If I don't have it attached I don't have access to it. I have a Canvas with 2 Buttons and 1 Textfield. where should i attach the script? If i press ok, then there is a little chance to bring "NO" to front. this means i have to bind the NO function to the OK function like you can see in my script

Comment: 1. add the script to only one object; 2. point both buttons `onClick` handlers to this object to corresponding methods

Comment: i figured it already out. i edited my Post. thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

The best possible solution is adding an empty parent (or any object for that matter). The simplest way would be a parent for simplicity's sake. Now the parent would be the only one counting the points and the buttons would only call functions to change the same score:

Adding 2 buttons (or more) to the same script:

```
public Button YesButton;
public Button NoButton;
```

Capturing their clicks and counting points all at once:

```
YesButton.onClick.AddListener(() => Score(1));
NoButton.onClick.AddListener(() => Score(5));
```

This would pretty much go in the Start() function. None of it needs to repeat.
After that the code counts points **CORRECTLY**

***FOR ADDITIONAL COMMANDS UPON CLICKING***

**CHANGE THE SCORE FUNCTION TO DO THE REST OR ADD NEW FUNCTIONS WHICH CALL SCORE AND DISABLE THE BUTTONS**